# Metrics list doesn't show up on grafana if prometheus doesn't have a scrape config

Tags: prometheus, grafana

I have been experimenting with my Prometheus setup and I ended up with the following:
[image: Prometheus setup]

- `Prometheus Write` is scraping all my exporter and writing to InfluxDB. Local storage is disabled. The configuration contains, the scraping config the service discovery config, remote read and remote write.
- `Prometheus Read` only contains the remote read and write config. Local storage is also disabled.
- `Grafana` datasource config is pointing to `Prometheus Read`.

This works fine. I can see all my series on `Grafana` and it's quite fast. Unfortunately, when opening the query editor, the metrics list doesn't contain anything:
[image: Grafana metrics list]

Where is the list of metrics coming from? Is it possible to get it to work without having to query the Prometheus instance that is doing the scraping?

Comment: You can add influxDB as a datasource in Grafana. Would that not simplify things?

Comment: Yes I can, unfortunately, I have a large amount of dashboards that have been written using the Prometheus datasource. If I can't find any solution to this question I will probably switch to querying InfluxDB directly like you mentioned.